# Lines with AirPrint from iOS 13 but not macOS 10.15

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I’m on tech support duty at the in-laws over Christmas, but this one has me stumped, any help appreciated.

They have an “HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M176n” which has been working fine for many years. Recently though AirPrint from phones has stopped working, or rather that lines are appearing on prints. See this example, cropped somewhat heavily to remove living people, but there are maybe 30-40 of these lines across a normal print:

[image: A crop of a print showing the lines.]

Printing from macOS 10.15 via AirPrint, or from Windows machines still works perfectly, so it can’t be toner or the imaging drum (although both are reporting that they need to be replaced in the near future…).

I’ve tried updating the firmware to the latest available (it went up from a 2013xx version to a 2016xx version) with no luck, and I’ve been through all the settings but there’s no obvious things to try: the AirPrint implementation is pretty opaque.

So is this an iOS 13 incompatibility that’s been introduced? The backup is to copy the images over to the computer before trying to print them which is acceptable, but not great if the printer advertises AirPrint.

Comment: Filed this with Apple’s feedback assistant as an iOS 13 bug report as well.